Excel Labs - Assign a Range to a Variable
This might be a really silly question, but does anyone know how to set a specific range equal to a variable? In the image below, I can't assign A1:A10 equal to _sheet, for example. In my specific use case, I cannot use the name manager since it tethers the range to a specific sheet. Ideally, I would also not like to pass it as a parameter.


If INDIRECT("A1:A10") is not what you're looking for, please explain what is _cell and what are the expected results for a few instances of _cell.

@VBasic2008, this is exactly the intended result, thank you! It returns an array I can index inside the lambda. If you post it I'll mark it as solution. _cell is literally the active cell, sent as the reference point for various Index Matches and other functions, and is irrelevant in this regard.

Hey, could you provide more context? If you're trying to get the row index of the current cell within a range, could you try =LAMBDA(range, ROW()-MIN(ROW(range)))(A1:A10)?

@nkalvi, the question was answered best by VBasic2008 in a comment. Should I delete this question or post his comment as a solution myself?

Usually volatile functions such as INDIRECT are avoided - you may want to read about it. It may not matter in your particular task.

@nkalvi, while I prefer non-volatile functions (and have the INDIRECT() nested within an IF() to curb volatility), my objective is to supply a range as a variable within my custom named function, as shown in the image above. The function is in the Excel Labs environment, which does not recognize simply typing A1:A10 as a range. The ranges I need may be 2 dimensional as well, such as A1:Z10.

If the answer I posted is not what you're trying to do, I'll delete it.

You can create a separate Lambda that will return A1:A10 like this:
A1ToA10 = LAMBDA(_cell,
    LET(
        r,ROW(_cell),
        c,COLUMN(_cell),
        OFFSET(_cell,-(r-1),-(c-1),10)
    ))  
;  


This will work on any sheet based on the given input

Thank you, but this is a little bulky, especially if I'd need 10 more of these.

What do you mean by "10 more of these"?

In this lambda, I'm using _rng as a variable to denote a specific space on the sheet/file, that I can INDEX() against with array functions to pull values from, to perform computations against. That being said, it's unlikely that I will only be pulling from one range, and will be specifying many more. This will clutter my Labs page and make the pertinent code difficult to parse.

Ok - then INDIRECT might be a better solution
